# Serialize/deserialize image mask in FiftyOne App

Tags: json, object-detection, fiftyone

I'd like to use the FiftyOne application for evaluating instance segmentation predictions. I used the the downloadable quickstart dataset for start and I created my own `samples.json` file for the ground truth and prediction data, which can be loaded by `Dataset.from_dir`. The json file in the tutorial contains only bounding boxes, but no masks. In the documentation I found only masks that are set to `None`, but I would need them.

```
{
  "samples": [
    {
      "filepath": "some_image.png",
      "tags": [
        "validation"
      ],
      "metadata": null,
      "uniqueness": 0.998,
      "ground_truth": {
        "_cls": "Detections",
        "detections": [
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "efd81c917c9a49dc9f8aca3f"
            },
            "_cls": "Detection",
            "label": "1",
            "bounding_box": [
              0.62609375,
              0.27044921875,
              0.030078124999999956,
              0.009550781250000001
            ],
            "mask": ???,
          }
        ]
      },
      "predictions": {
        "_cls": "Detections",
        "detections": [
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "6db44c71c1414b8989c92255"
            },
            "_cls": "Detection",
            "label": "1",
            "bounding_box": [
              0.3303889036178589,
              0.4432219862937927,
              0.07914596796035767,
              0.02226179838180542
            ],
            "mask": ???,
            "confidence": 0.999962329864502
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem I have is that how should I create the `mask` property for the segmentation mask? It is a numpy array and not serializable by default. The `Dataset.from_dir` uses the `core.utils.deserialize_numpy_array` function for loading the dataset, so I tried to use `serialize_numpy_array` with no success for saving the dataset.

So what would be the best way to write the mask into the json file that is deserializable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dataset.from_dir()` syntax is generally used for well-defined dataset types like a dataset stored on disk in the [`COCODetectionDataset`](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/dataset_creation/datasets.html#cocodetectiondataset) format.

In your case, when loading a custom dataset that does not directly correspond to one of the related dataset types, then the recommended approach is to write a [simple Python loop and construct your dataset one sample at a time](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/dataset_creation/index.html#custom-formats).

In this case, you do just need to [load your mask as a numpy array and store it in the `mask` attribute of your detection object](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/using_datasets.html#instance-segmentations).

```py
import glob
import fiftyone as fo

images_patt = "/path/to/images/*"

# Ex: your custom label format
annotations = {
    "/path/to/images/000001.jpg": [
        {"bbox": ..., "label": ..., "mask": ...},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}

# Create samples for your data
samples = []
for filepath in glob.glob(images_patt):
    sample = fo.Sample(filepath=filepath)

    # Convert detections to FiftyOne format
    detections = []
    for objects in annotations[filepath]:
        label = obj["label"]

        # Bounding box coordinates should be relative values
        # in [0, 1] in the following format:
        # [top-left-x, top-left-y, width, height]
        bounding_box = obj["bbox"]

        # Boolean or 0/1 Numpy array 
        mask = obj["mask"]
        
        detection = fo.Detection(
            label=label,
            bounding_box=bounding_box,
            mask=mask,
        )

        detections.append(detection)

    # Store detections in a field name of your choice
    sample["ground_truth"] = fo.Detections(detections=detections)

    samples.append(sample)

# Create dataset
dataset = fo.Dataset("my-detection-dataset")
dataset.add_samples(samples)
```

Predictions could either be loaded at the same time as the ground truth, or you can always iterate over your dataset in the future and [add predictions at a later time](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/dataset_creation/index.html#model-predictions):

```py
import fiftyone as fo

# Ex: your custom predictions format
predictions = {
    "/path/to/images/000001.jpg": [
        {"bbox": ..., "label": ..., "mask": ..., "score": ...},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}

# Add predictions to your samples
for sample in dataset:
    filepath = sample.filepath

    # Convert predictions to FiftyOne format
    detections = []
    for obj in predictions[filepath]:
        label = obj["label"]
        confidence = obj["score"]

        # Bounding box coordinates should be relative values
        # in [0, 1] in the following format:
        # [top-left-x, top-left-y, width, height]
        bounding_box = obj["bbox"]
        
        # Boolean or 0/1 Numpy array 
        mask = obj["mask"]

        detection = fo.Detection(
            label=label,
            bounding_box=bounding_box,
            confidence=confidence,
        )

        detection["mask"] = mask

        detections.append(detection)

    # Store detections in a field name of your choice
    sample["predictions"] = fo.Detections(detections=detections)

    sample.save()
```

Note that the exact structure of how to parse your custom label format will depend on how you are storing the data. This is just one example that stores labels in a dictionary keyed by media filepaths. You may first need to parse and convert your labels, for example into the expected bounding box format.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

This way I can create a dataset indeed, which can be fed to the 51 App such as ```session = fo.launch_app(dataset)```. But for example I cannot do the following ```dataset.sort_by("eval_fp", reverse=True).filter_labels("predictions", F("eval") == "fp")```, because no "eval_fp" field exists.
Creating a 'samples.json' (similar to the quickstart dataset) and loading it with the ```Dataset.from_dir``` somehow generates a dataset, which is enhanced with some extra useful fields.

Comment: Those extra fields need to be generated explicitly for your dataset and should not be copied from one dataset to another. For example, the "eval_fp" field is populated by running detection evaluation on your dataset: https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/evaluation.html#detections

and the "uniqueness" field is created using this workflow: https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/brain.html#image-uniqueness

Comment: Oh, great. It is a bit unintuitive that the ```evaluate_detections``` alters the dataset itself, but it is good news anyway.

Comment: The main reason to use the evaluation in FiftyOne is actually because it adds fields to the dataset itself. In other evaluation tools, you just get the dataset-wide statistics, but FiftyOne will store the individual false/true positives/negatives on your labels directly so you can query them and dig in to see how your model performed on specific examples.

Comment: I used one or two evaluations earlier, but only scratched the surface and tried some basic things. There is a lot to explore.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. I created the samples and added them to the dataset, which now contains ground_truth and predictions masks (boolean numpy arrays),  but the masks are not displayed in the application, when I launch it, only the bounding boxes. Does this implicate that I did something wrong during the dataset creation, or the display shall be configured somehow? (When I load a coco dataset from the disk providing the necessary label types, it is okay.)

Comment: Right, that sounds like the masks were not loaded correctly. The App will display the masks automatically if they are in the correct format. Could you jump on the FiftyOne Users Slack channel and provide some more context, it will be easier to debug: https://join.slack.com/t/fiftyone-users/shared_invite/zt-s6936w7b-2R5eVPJoUw008wP7miJmPQ